# bootstrap 2.0 Activating tab and data by url within tab-content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen numerous questions generally touching this subject, I know exactly what needs to be done but I'm not "fluent" with jQuery therefore, I cannot successfully do this.

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="activate">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1"><h1>Data for Tab 1</h2></div>
     <div id="tab2">
         <a href="#tab1" rel="taburl" data-toggle="tab">Take me to tab content #1</a>
     </div>
```

Ideally, the data of that tab is switched to #tab1, however, the tab will not switch to `active` class on the `href="#tab1"` (stays active on `#tab2` but displays the data from `#tab1`)

I figured I could use the `.first()` method and target the first occurrence of `href="#tab1` and `.addClass('active')` to this li. But I do not know how to select the li for anylink I link to it to directly target that `href` ID

I really do not know if this can be done. Can I inject the `href` data from the link (with jQuery) then add it to the tab link and make it active.

And again, the `data-toggle="tab"` switches to the right content but will not update the active tab on the navbar,

so is there a way to select that exact 'tab' and `.addClass('active')` to the `<li>` once I've fired the link.

Thank you for your time.

### JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE

http://jsfiddle.net/epiceon/M6NQJ/1/

Comment: I'm confused by statements like "tab of that data is switched". Can you have a re-read of your question and maybe separate what you're asking from what you're thinking?

Comment: @Sinetheta sorry. I was just in a hurry to write this out and made a lot of mistakes. I corrected it. I switches correctly, but it stays on the active tab from before the link was click. Thus, not updating :/

Comment: @KyleMonti i don't understand your question, so you want to pre-activate tab 3 upon page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch between tabs like that you're going to need to call `tab('show')` again on the tab you intend that button to go to.

On a side note, you should consider updating your version to 2.0.3 if you're using tabs. They fixed a few bugs (mostly with tabs on the left or right) but even dropping in the new navs.less file might save you a headache down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered something similiar when trying to manually close a tab within itself.

Heres the working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WnQvF/8/

Note that i just copypasted from my project. So the solution might not be the cleanest for your problem but you will get how it works.
Remember to name the Tab-Buttons and the Button within Tab 3.